# Configure passwordless SSH between OCI VM hosts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, putty

I have 2 Ubuntu VMs hosted on OCI and one local Ubuntu VM which I want to configure to connect using passwordless SSH.

I downloaded public and private SSH keys and I created .ppk file to connect using Putty.

```
sudo apt-get install putty-tools
puttygen 1.ppk -O private-openssh -o keyname.pem
ssh -i keyname.pem  ubuntu@123.123.123.121
```

So far it's working fine.
But when I try:

```
test@test-VirtualBox:/opt$ ssh-copy-id -i keyname.pem  ubuntu@123.123.123.123
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: failed to open ID file 'keyname.pem.pub': No such file
```

Do you know what is the proper way to implement this?

Comment: Silly question but why are you using putty over the 'regular' openssh client?

Comment: Because I have Windows machine for working with web config panel for OCI

Answer (score 0):

`man ssh-copy-id` excerpt:

> **-i identity_file**
> Use only the key(s) contained in identity_file (rather than looking for identities via ssh-add(1) or in the default_ID_file).  ***If the filename does not end in .pub this is added.***  If the filename is omitted, the default_ID_file is used.

`ssh-copy-id` expects a your key-pairs to be named

```
mykey.xyz          # private key
mykey.xyz.pub      # public key
```

It expects both keys to be present.